# Sky Force 2014: spaceship upgrade detail?

Tags: android, sky-force-2014

In [Sky Force 2014](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.idreams.skyforcehd&hl=en), is there any way to see the details of hangar upgrades? E.g. I like to see what improvements would upgrading the main cannon brings (like "+10% strength, +20% frequency").

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, actually there isn't a way to see these stats or even if the upgrades consists of percentages, they might consist of points, we just don't know.

I can tell you what the maximum level each upgrade goes to.

Health: 5 Levels (So the 50 upgrades)

Main Cannon: 4 Levels (40 upgrades)

Wing Cannons: 5 Levels (50 upgrades)

Magnet: 4 Levels (40 upgrades)

Missiles: 5 Levels (50 upgrades)

I'm not a 100%, but you have to remember this is always changing as they keep expanding the game.

---

Maximum level upgrade in v1.33:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea there was a limit! By the way any idea for http://android.stackexchange.com/q/96816/12202 ?

Comment: I don't have that button, Using an iphone. Sorry.

Comment: oh wow, interesting, I wouldn't have guessed it was Android only!

Comment: What i think that button is, is a while ago they were trying to make it so you could buy coins, like a pay to play sort of deal. And you could buy upgrades, and speed up time. But I think they might have removed that feature all together. So you could purchase those "coins" and if you were at 0/10 planes, you could use the coins to buy more planes and keep playing.

Comment: On Android this button is used to get a new plane in exchange for watching an advertisement for 30 seconds. Unfortunately, on Genymotion the option is greyed out and I suspect that because whatever reason videos ads don't show up there. I don't know why.

Comment: I think they basically removed support any other methods of making money in that game other than the ads at the top of the game when you're in your hanger or maps menu.

Comment: I still have the button working on my Android phone (Galaxy S5) though: on Android it seems like the button is greyed out only on Genymotion :/

Comment: http://www.cheaterscircle.com/sky-force-2014-cheats-and-guides/ says: "8. Removing ads tricks. Not everyone has patience for annoying ads and if you are among of them you should do this trick to simply remove the advertisement banner from Sky Force 2014. Just turn your phone into airplane mode or shut off the wi-fi and the cellular so you can pull it off for free. In game there is an ad-removal feature but with this cheat, you don’t need to spend cash anymore."
I think for some reason ads don't appear on Genymotion, hence the button is greyed out.

Comment: My Genymotion virtual device has Wi-Fi on and airplane mode off, so theoretically the ads should work :/

Comment: I added a screenshot showing the maximum level upgrade for each spaceship's feature.