# In Sky Force: Reloaded, what are the maximum upgrade levels of your ship hardware?

Tags: sky-force-reloaded

Similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202251), what are the maximum levels for each piece of ship hardware that can be upgraded in the hangar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The maximum levels for each of these pieces of hardware is different than the earlier game, [*Sky Force 2014*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/202929/183113).

As of 31<sup>st</sup> March 2017 the current app version 1.81 has the following upgrade levels. These increases were probably spread out through updates 7 and 8 as the forums have people complaining about no new upgrades in update #9.

- Health        5
- Main Cannon   6
- Wing Cannons  6
- Magnet        3
- Missiles      4
- Laser         3
- Energy Shield 3
- Mega Bomb     3

[image: Maximum upgrade levels for version 1.81 of Sky Force Reloaded]

**[UPDATE #9](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?p=3972950#post3972950)**

On 3<sup>rd</sup> February 2017 an app update (v 1.81) was published.

**[UPDATE #8](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?p=3959225#post3959225)**

On 5<sup>th</sup> January 2017 an app update (v 1.7) was published. Upgrade changes were made as follows:

- Laser         2 → 3
- Energy Shield 2 → 3
- Mega Bomb     2 → 3

**UPDATE #7**

Unknown release date.

**[UPDATE #6](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?p=3930069#post3930069)**

On 28<sup>th</sup> October 2016 an app update (v 1.6) was published. Upgrade changes were made as follows:

- Health      4 → 5
- Main Cannon 5 → 6
- Missiles    3 → 4

**[UPDATE #5](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?p=3907715#post3907715)**

On 7<sup>th</sup> September 2016 an app update (v 1.5) was published.

**[UPDATE #4](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?p=3904439#post3904439)**

On 30<sup>th</sup> August 2016 an app update (v 1.41) was published. Upgrade changes were made as follows:

- Main Cannon 4 → 5

**UPDATE #3**

On 3<sup>rd</sup> August 2016 an app update (v 1.30) was published. Upgrade changes were made as follows:

- Wing Cannons 4 → 5

**UPDATE #2**

On 15<sup>th</sup> July 2016 an app update (v 1.20) was published. Upgrade changes were made as follows:

- Main Cannon  3 → 4

**[UPDATE #1](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?p=3907715#post3907715)**

On 17<sup>th</sup> June 2016 an app update (v 1.10) was published. Upgrade changes were made as follows:

- Health       3 → 4
- Magnet       2 → 3
- Missiles     2 → 3

Comment: I'm still playing it and it looks like that "Missiles" got stuck at Level 2. They are so awesome. I'm hoping that there is some kind of balancing or leveling mechanism which will allow further development of them. I'll report back here after a while on the progress.

Comment: I think each upgrade provides a greater power boost than they did in 2014.  I felt level grinding was tedious in 2014 but in reloaded, it was well balanced with progressive level difficulty.

Comment: All, thanks for keeping this updated.  I had to delete this game since I'm running out of room on my 16GB iPhone.  Anyway, please update or remove the photos, if you keep this up to date.

Comment: What changes happen on each weapon level?

Comment: @JafarAli each upgrade makes the weapons do one of the following: a) more damage, b) cover more of the screen, c) fire more projectiles.

Comment: @RLH way too much star farming in reloaded too imho. Very tedious game, almost forcing  people to buy the x2 star and/or the no-ad options.

Answer (score 2):

Max upgrades (2016-11-23):

- Health: 5
- Main Cannon: 6
- Wing Cannons: 5
- Magnet: 3
- Missiles: 4
- Laser:    2
- Energy Shield: 2
- Mega Bomb: 2