# How many stars does one need to reach the maximum levels for each piece of ship hardware that can be upgraded in the hangar?

Tags: android, sky-force-reloaded

In [Sky Force Reloaded](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.idreams.SkyForceReloaded2016&hl=en_US&gl=US), there are [many](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/269628/19400) upgrade levels to one's ship hardware. How many stars does one need to reach the maximum levels for each piece of ship hardware that can be upgraded in the hangar?